# FirebaseAuth.currentUser as a Flow?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement Firebase Auth to my project, and I'm trying to create a flow with Firebase current User. But I can't obtain in real time the user in my viewmodel. I have two buttons to login and logout and another to get a Log with the currentUser, but when I login and logout this variable doesn't change.

This in FireBaseAuthService:

```
val currentUser: Flow<FirebaseUser?> = flow {
  val user = firebaseAuth.currentUser
  emit(user)
}
```

This in AuthRepository:

```
val currentUser: Flow<FirebaseUser?> = firebaseAuthService.currentUser
```

And in ViewModel I tried:

```
private val _currentUser = authRepository.currentUser.asLiveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
val currentUser: LiveData<FirebaseUser?>
get() = _currentUser
```

and

```
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        authRepository.currentUser.collect{
            currentUser = it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To track the user auth state, you have to use a [FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener):

> Listener called when there is a change in the authentication state.

This means that you'll be notified immediately when the user state changes, either from signed in to signed out or vice versa. When it comes to flows, in this case, it is recommended to use a [callbackFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html). So to propagate the user auth state, from the repository right to the UI, I would use the following approach:

```
override fun getAuthState(viewModelScope: CoroutineScope) = callbackFlow {
    val authStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { auth ->
        trySend(auth.currentUser == null)
    }
    auth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    awaitClose {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }
}.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), auth.currentUser == null)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! I've implemented my Firebase Auth like you in your repo. Now in the fragment I have two buttons for Login and Logout. When I click them, I call getAuhtState() and it returns true for logout and false for login, I think this is correct. But is posible to get this as a Variable in the ViewModel, and do some automatized actions on this changes?
Anyway I try collectAsState() in my fragment: private fun AuthState() {
        val isUserSignedOut = viewModel.getAuthState().collectAsState().value
And it doesn't work (unresolved reference), I'm not using Composable. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I did it:(In my viewmodel) private val userCurrent: StateFlow<Boolean> get() = authRepository.getAuthState(viewModelScope) Is this correct? It will change if I logout from another fragment of the application? And how I can update the fragment when this variable change the state? (collectAsState) not working. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I did it with: lifecycleScope.launch{
            userViewModel.userCurrent.collect{
                updateUI(it)
            }
        }
Going to try to sign in and sign out from another fragment and see what happens.